# NextJS ISR pages returning 404 on AWS Amplify, whereas running fine on localhost

Tags: next.js, aws-amplify

I am testing a NextJS application* on AWS Amplify. The site works fine locally. All pages, including Incremental Static Regeneration (ISR) pages are loaded and working. Even, when running `npm run build`, it shows that the ISR pages have been created and I can see these within `.next/static/chunks/pages/...`

However, on Amplify, the ISR pages return a 404.

I have the parameters within `getStaticPaths()` as `fallback: false` and within `getStaticProps()` as `revalidate: 1`.

Within CloudWatch, I get the following error:

```
[x-amplify-log][INFO] app response status_code=404 Not Found 
headers=x-nextjs-matched-path: /blog/page/[page_index], 
x-powered-by: redacted (7), etag: "zelzrux0qt2i9", 
content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8, 
vary: Accept-Encoding, content-encoding: gzip, 
date: Mon, 08 May 2023 13:25:32 GMT, connection: keep-alive, 
keep-alive: redacted (9), transfer-encoding: chunked, 
x-amplify-internal-request-id: d4c3b5ff-56a0-4bf4-b4c6-3d1116ced0e1, 
x-amplify-internal-metrics: CustomerServerReadinessCheck;dur=533, 
RuntimeTotal;dur=978, RuntimeInitialization;dur=543, 
CustomerServerCall;dur=429
```

Any idea what could be happening here?

Thanks!

*(Repo: https://github.com/bradtraversy/next-markdown-blog)

Answer (score 1):

**TLDR;**

Within `getStaticPaths()`, replace `fallback: false`  with `fallback: 'blocking'`

**Reason:**

Since I had `fallback` set to `false` and the page had not been pre-rendered, Nextjs returned a 404.

Once I changed `fallback` to `'blocking'`, if the page had not been pre-rendered, Next will load that apge. Once it does this the first time, it will be cached and then served like other pre-rendered pages.

Comment: This was the answer for me, so I was generating static pages for my site on AWS Amplify, I could see the pages were being generated on the build step, could see them in the folder on the build artefact but if I went to the site with JS turned off the pages were 404, very odd as the static file is there, this was only happening on subfolder pages, root pages were working as expected! Changing it to blocking now is working and SEO tools are finding all the pages! Thanks Brad